# Show lines through circumcenters of triangles concurrent with complex numbers

Tags: geometry, contest-math

Cyclic quadrilateral $ABCD$ has circumcenter $O$. Point $O$ does not lie on any of the sides of the quadrilateral. Let $O_1,O_2,O_3,O_4$ denote the circumcenters of $\triangle OAB, \triangle OBC, \triangle OCD, \triangle ODA$, respectively. Given that diagonals $AC$ and $BD$ intersect at $P$, prove that $O_1O_3, O_2O_4,$ and $OP$ are concurrent.

[image]

I found this problem on an article about using complex numbers in geometry, so I was wondering about a solution using complex numbers.

Here's what I have so far. The method I use will lead to a solution, but I was wondering if there were any computation shortcuts.

Let lowercase letters be the complex number associated with the uppercase point. By definition, we have $(o_1,\frac{a}{2})\perp(o,a)$ and $(o_1,\frac{b}{2})\perp(o,b)$. It follows that $\frac{o_1-\frac{a}{2}}{a}\in i\mathbb{R},\frac{o_1-\frac{b}{2}}{b}\in i\mathbb{R}$. This means that $\frac{o_1-\frac{a}{2}}{a}=-\frac{\overline{o_1}-\frac{1}{2a}}{\frac{1}{a}}$, which simplifies to $o_1=a-a^2\overline{o_1}$. Similarly, $o_1=b-b^2\overline{o_1}$. Solving for $\overline{o_1}$ and in both equations and then equating the two, we get $\frac{a-o_1}{a^2}=\frac{b-o_1}{b^2}$, or $o_1=\frac{ab}{a+b}$. Similarly, we get $o_2=\frac{bc}{b+c},o_3=\frac{cd}{c+d},o_4=\frac{da}{d+a}$. We can compute $X=O_1O_3\cap O_2O_4$ using the well-known formula: $AB\cap CD=\frac{(\overline{a}b-a\overline{b})(c-d)-(a-b)(\overline{c}d-c\overline{d})}{(\overline{a}-\overline{b})(c-d)-(a-b)(\overline{c}-\overline{d})}$, for $a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{C}$. Using this formula, we can also compute $P=AC\cap BD$. It remains to show that $P,O,X$ are collinear, or that $\left| \begin{array}{ccc}
p & \overline{p} & 1 \\
x & \overline{x} & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \end{array} \right|=0$, or $x\overline{p}=\overline{x}p$. But the formula for $AB\cap CD$ is quite ugly so $x$ (and $p$) are very big. Any ideas?

Also any synthetic ideas would be nice to see!